# Reactjs Module not found | Css import

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I will try to be concise, I must work on a Reactjs project for school project, my task is to take a existing html/css theme and and put it in React components.

But I have a problem since the start, I used CreateReactApp for a clean start and import index.css of the theme.
Create a basic form base on the theme and have this error. (She disapear when I delete index.css)

Error I see
[Failed to compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK0pE.png)

> ./src/css/index.css
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve '../images/category-1-bg.jpg' in
>   'C:\Users\50031\Documents\React-Project-master\src\css'

Structure of the project is that
[Structure project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSp2h.png)

Thanks so much, I already check for an answer but I suck as hell in code and understand nothing.... Sorry

Comment: Please try to show your errors within the post.

Comment: Done, sorry first time I post here :s

Comment: try replacing `import style from './css/index.css'` with:
`import './css/index.css'`

Comment: Done, no change :(

Comment: I try something wit the img concerned and find something strange, it's like the compiler forget one folder everytime ->

../images/category-1-bg.jpg | real position ../images/journal/category-1-bg.jpg
  other case   ../empty-card-bg.jpg | real position ../images/empty-card-bg

Comment: please show us how you import the image file in the `index.css` file

Comment: background: url('../images/empty-cart-bg.jpg') no-repeat;

I don't touch the theme

Comment: please remove the single quotes around the file location: `background: url(../images/empty-cart-bg.jpg) no-repeat;`

Comment: Always same error with and without quotes :s

Comment: did you drop the images into the public folder? /public/css/index.css and public/images/empty-cart-bg.jpg, is this what you have as your file structure?

Answer (score 0):

Your images directory is not inside css directory and that is what the error says. This is because somewhere in your `index.css` you have not assigned correct path for the images. Assign correct paths to the images in your `index.css` and the app should compile.

Answer (score 0):

Install [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader) so that it will include the image during build time.